# Loop over nested array and filter out all entries?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object that looks like the one below - How can I loop over all items inside each ID/Keys, and return all entries so a single filtered object in ES6?

Should I have a look at .filter/.map/reduce or maybe something like Object.entries? I've tried .reduce, but I cant quite wrap my head around it :(

```
{
"system_events": {
    "1013": [{
            "id": 25899,
            "timestamp": "2017-08-15T21:26:42Z",
            "type": "alarm",
            "code": 190,
            "title": "",
            "description": "",
            "appeared": "2017-08-15T21:26:40Z",
            "disappeared": null,
            "acknowlegded": null,
            "solved": null,
            "system_name": "Randers pr 44b sidste station"
        }, {
            "id": 26157,
            "timestamp": "2017-08-15T21:32:17Z",
            "type": "alarm",
            "code": 190,
            "title": "",
            "description": "",
            "appeared": "2017-08-15T21:32:06Z",
            "disappeared": null,
            "acknowlegded": null,
            "solved": null,
            "system_name": "Randers pr 44b sidste station"
        }
    ],
    "1015": [{
            "id": 23777,
            "timestamp": "2017-08-15T20:38:08Z",
            "type": "alarm",
            "code": 191,
            "title": "",
            "description": "",
            "appeared": "2017-08-15T20:38:00Z",
            "disappeared": null,
            "acknowlegded": null,
            "solved": null,
            "system_name": "Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"
        }, {
            "id": 23779,
            "timestamp": "2017-08-15T20:38:08Z",
            "type": "alarm",
            "code": 190,
            "title": "",
            "description": "",
            "appeared": "2017-08-15T20:37:58Z",
            "disappeared": null,
            "acknowlegded": null,
            "solved": null,
            "system_name": "Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"
        }
    ]
}}
```

Wished output would be:

```
The example of the output is this: {
[{
        "id": 25899,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-15T21:26:42Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 190,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-15T21:26:40Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Randers pr 44b sidste station"
    }, {
        "id": 26157,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-15T21:32:17Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 190,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-15T21:32:06Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Randers pr 44b sidste station"
    }, {
        "id": 23777,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-15T20:38:08Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 191,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-15T20:38:00Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"
    }, {
        "id": 23779,
        "timestamp": "2017-08-15T20:38:08Z",
        "type": "alarm",
        "code": 190,
        "title": "",
        "description": "",
        "appeared": "2017-08-15T20:37:58Z",
        "disappeared": null,
        "acknowlegded": null,
        "solved": null,
        "system_name": "Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: yes you should try

Comment: can you give an example of your expected output format

Comment: Sure, I want to collect all items inside each "ID/Number", all have it all in a filtered object... Makes sense?

Comment: @nuffsaid this is not an example of the output as requested by Reiner...

Comment: The keys in the members of each array are all the same, so you'd end up with just a single object (if I'm understanding the question correctly). An example of the desired output would be helpful, as other have said.

Comment: I've updated the example with a wished output

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this

```
Object.keys(obj.system_events).map((id) => {
    return obj.system_events[id];
}).reduce((result, array) => {
    return result.concat(array);
}, [])
```

if you want to add a filtering search criteria you may try something like this.

```
let searchCriteria = {
   id: 23779,
   code: 190
};
Object.keys(obj.system_events).map((id) => {
    return obj.system_events[id];
}).reduce((result, array) => {
   return result.concat(array);
}, []).filter((obj) => {
   // do your filtering here.
   let field;
   for (field in searchCriteria) {
      if (searchCriteria[field] !== obj[field]) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this??

If so do not just copy/paste, instead try to understand why and how its working as well.

```js
let jsonObj = {"system_events":{"1013":[{"id":25899,"timestamp":"2017-08-15T21:26:42Z","type":"alarm","code":190,"title":"","description":"","appeared":"2017-08-15T21:26:40Z","disappeared":null,"acknowlegded":null,"solved":null,"system_name":"Randers pr 44b sidste station"},{"id":26157,"timestamp":"2017-08-15T21:32:17Z","type":"alarm","code":190,"title":"","description":"","appeared":"2017-08-15T21:32:06Z","disappeared":null,"acknowlegded":null,"solved":null,"system_name":"Randers pr 44b sidste station"}],"1015":[{"id":23777,"timestamp":"2017-08-15T20:38:08Z","type":"alarm","code":191,"title":"","description":"","appeared":"2017-08-15T20:38:00Z","disappeared":null,"acknowlegded":null,"solved":null,"system_name":"Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"},{"id":23779,"timestamp":"2017-08-15T20:38:08Z","type":"alarm","code":190,"title":"","description":"","appeared":"2017-08-15T20:37:58Z","disappeared":null,"acknowlegded":null,"solved":null,"system_name":"Favrskov Svenstrup gyvelvej"}]}};

let data = [];
Object.keys(jsonObj.system_events).forEach(key => {
jsonObj.system_events[key].forEach(d => data.push(d));
});

console.log(data)
```